# Oracle Evaluate condition incorrect

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've got a trouble querying on of two Oracle databases.

The query is:

```
SELECT trunc(null)
FROM dual 
WHERE (null is null 
       or SYSDATE >= TRUNC(null))
```

(The NULL is actually a param, passed to a query, which may be null, so I cut the query short).

On the production DB it works OK and the response is NULL.

On the dev DB I catch an error, that TRUNC can't be applied to NUMBER and expects DATE (ORA-00932).

Obviously the production DB skips everything in the condition after OR, and the developer one executes the part after OR.

I do know a solution to fix the problem by adding CAST(MY_PARAM as date) to every query, but it doesn't really suit me - there's to much code to change.

The question is: is there some setting in the DB I've missed, that prevents condition scan after it's already true or does it dependent on DB version?

My production db is:

- Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
- PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
- CORE 11.2.0.4.0 Production
- TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
- NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

My dev db is:

- Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
- PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
- CORE 11.2.0.1.0 Production
- TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
- NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

Comment: You should change your queries.  Having type mismatches in the query that are short-circuited by boolean logic seems quite dangerous.  Even more so for a production system.

Comment: "NULL is actually a param". So the query is something like `WHERE (:dt is null or SYSDATE >= TRUNC(:dt))`? Then obviously you are passing a numeric type to that bind variable. Pass a date type and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE (PARAM IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE TRUNC(PARAM) END
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: I can't change my queries, they are long like 50 lines each have LOTS of conditions, and there are hundredes of them . The question is how is oracl making it's scan inside the conditions.

Comment: You can't know. Oracle freely choose the order of checking the conditions in WHERE clause.

Comment: use CASE in WHERE clause :